# Opera advert appearing in Chrome, possibly linked to having Opera installed

Tags: google-chrome, opera

I sometimes get an Opera ad like this one appear in Google Chrome.

[image]

I do have Opera installed but I don't use it. I tried clicking on the 'Learn more' link and it opened Opera.

I assume possibly this is some sort of Opera program running on startup.

I consider this to be malware, given that it is unwanted and unsolicited, but I am not 100% sure the source.

I have however now uninstalled Opera, so I can't confirm if there were any Opera processes running on Windows startup that perhaps caused this.

Can anyone confirm that my suspicion that this advert is linked to having Opera installed is correct?

Comment: Have the Opera pop-ups disappeared since you uninstalled Opera?

Comment: I didn't pay much attention to when they appeared - they weren't very frequent before, perhaps only shortly on starting Windows, but I only uninstalled Opera five minutes ago, so I can't say for sure that they have disappeared, in that I would not expect them to appear that often. Ideally someone would have seen similar popups and know where they come from.

Comment: Please accept my answer by pressing on the green tick and upvoting it to let people know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

This ad is served by Opera. It is a pop-up from Opera promoting its new Instagram feature. There's no need to worry, it isn't malicious, and after uninstalling Opera, it should disappear.